# environment variables not found on Visual Studio 2008 with OpenCL

Tags: visual-studio, opencl

so for my internship I need to make a piece of software suitable for processing on the GPU. As long as my pc at my 'work' isnt set up, Im using LogMeIn to access my pc at home, with an ATI HD6850. I installed Visual Studio 2008 professional, and the OpenCL SDK. When I load the first program found at http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/documentation/ImageConvolutionOpenCL/Pages/ImageConvolutionUsingOpenCL.aspx and build it, it says that it can't find the following environment variables: $(atistreamsdkroot). But ATI stream has already for some time been APP isn't it?

Now the question: how do I solve this? I've looked through stackoverflow and other forums, but I couldn't really find something... Im I just the only one experiencing this, or is it just that simple to solve?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably looking for header or library files in a location on your disk that is relative to the **atistreamsdkroot** environment variable.  My guess is that you don't have this environment variable set on your system.  You can either change the path to these resources from using that environment variable to a hard-coded path, or you can define the environment variable on your system.

I'm not sure what operating system you have, but a simple search of the web should show you the steps to create a new environment variable.  The value of that environment variable should be the path to where you installed the sdk to on your system.

On a separate note, once you do build successfully, you may not be able to run this code on the GPU because you are using LogMeIn.  I'm not positive about this, but I *think* that software drivers are used to render remote machine screens via LogMeIn.  As a result, when the program tries to look for OpenCl-compatible platforms/devices, it will probably not find any.

Comment: I have windows7 ultimate 64-bit :) But where do I have to create that environment variable in Windows itself, or in Visual Studio? And where should it link to, since ATI Stream is outdated? To the APP ecquivalent I guess, but what's that? :P
My guess is that it will run, because some little programs from the amd site did run ;)
I indeed found a tut, but how should I name it? To what it is asking, atistreamsdkroot?

Comment: I really would like an answer please, because I don't know what to do (A)

Comment: Well, you can define the environment variable any way you like, but in Windows is probably the easiest.  Control Panel->System and Security->System, then Advanced System Settings, then Environment Variables button.  Add a new environment variable for atistreamsdkroot and set the value of it to the location of the sdk you installed (APP in your case I guess).